# How to compare Integer with integer array

Tags: java, android

i am new to android. I want to know how to compare Integer with integer array. There is a set of integer array (Ex) array_int={1,2,3,4} and single integer int i=2, here i want to compare both integers,and in case if single integer appears in array integer, i want to break the process.

```
for(i=0;i<integerArray.length;i++){
    if(singleinteger!=integerArray[i]){ // some action       }
else{
// Stop the action  }
```

In this case it compares both integer. and at the time when two integers are equal process getting break, otherwise it iteration action  till the loop getting end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple solution, use:

```
for (i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    if (singleInt != intArray[i]) {
        // some action
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

That will break from the loop when the two values are equal. However, some purists don't like the use of `break` since it can introduce readability issues, *especially* if your `some action` is large (in terms of lines of code) since that removes an exit condition far away from the `for` itself.

To fix that, you may want to consider reversing the sense of the `if` statement so that that exit condition is closer to the `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    if (singleInt == intArray[i])
        break;

    // some action
}
```

and that will also let you remove the `else` (that's the `else` itself, *not* its contents) since it's not needed any more.

But, if you're going to do that, you may as well incorporate it totally into the `for` and be done with it:

```
for (i = 0; (i < intArray.length) && (singleInt != intArray[i]); i++) {
    // some action
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i am trying out your solution, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Use a](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

```
break;
```

inside your loop.

Comment: It's not inside the loop. It's inside the `else` statement.

Comment: @HariRam to stop the action use `break;`

Comment: @Mahesh the `if`-`else` statement is inside the `for` loop. A `break` inside the `else` will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++ {
    if(singleinteger != integerArray[i] { 
        //some action
    }
    else { 
        break; //add this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can read up on Integer test [here](http://java.comsci.us/tutorial/icomp.html)

Otherwise in your code your simply missing the "exit" of your loop.

```
    for(i=0;i<integerArray.length;i++){
        if(singleinteger!=integerArray[i]){ // some action
    }else{
    // Stop the action  
       break;
    }
```

but that is only if you don't need to process the rest of your array.